# Extract a sentence with certain words from the text Python

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, data-science, text-extraction

I'm an absolute newbie in ML and got really stuck with the following problem. I need to train a model that can extract a sentence (or a piece of it) from the text if this sentence contains the info with certain words.

For example:

text = 'The jeans are blue they are cool. i Love the jeans jeans cost money. the Jeans i wear cost a lot. these jeans cost 200 dollars but i like them'

info = 'jeans cost'

result = 'these jeans cost 200 dollars'

So the text contains repeated words / phrases, missing punctuation marks, etc. My model has to find the piece which contains good info (with the price of the jeans) if there's one and return it (not create the answer -- just return it the way it is).

Where should I start? Looks like it's not about named entity recognition or anything like that, but more about an efficient search algorithm. Where the main problem is to define where the the desired piece starts and ends ('cause I can't rely on punctuation or upper case here). Or am I wrong? Any advice so much appreciated!

Thanks!!